# TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'encoding'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am running a keras/tensorflow model, when I try to save and process data to TFrecords as following the keras model tutorial, then it generates an error two errors as listed below
`TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'encoding'`  and when I comment this line then below line generates another error `NotFoundError: 519_IM-2131-2001.dcm.png; No such file or directory [Op:ReadFile]`

The code which generates these errors is following

```
`train_size = 30000 
 valid_size = 5000
 captions_per_image = 2
 images_per_file = 2000

 train_image_paths = image_paths[:train_size]
 num_train_files = int(np.ceil(train_size / images_per_file))
 train_files_prefix = os.path.join(tfrecords_dir, "train")

 valid_image_paths = image_paths[-valid_size:]
 num_valid_files = int(np.ceil(valid_size / images_per_file))
 valid_files_prefix = os.path.join(tfrecords_dir, "valid")

 tf.io.gfile.makedirs(tfrecords_dir)


 def bytes_feature(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


 def create_example(image_path, caption):
    feature = {
       "caption": bytes_feature(caption.str.encode()),
       "raw_image": bytes_feature(tf.io.read_file(image_path).numpy()),
       
 }
       return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))


  def write_tfrecords(file_name, image_paths):
  caption_list = []
  image_path_list = []
  for image_path in image_paths:
    captions = image_path_to_caption[image_path][:captions_per_image]
    caption_list.extend(captions)
    image_path_list.extend([image_path] * len(captions))

  with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file_name) as writer:
    for example_idx in range(len(image_path_list)):
        example = create_example(
            image_path_list[example_idx], caption_list[example_idx]
        )
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
  return example_idx + 1


  def write_data(image_paths, num_files, files_prefix):
    example_counter = 0
    for file_idx in tqdm(range(num_files)):
      file_name = files_prefix + "-%02d.tfrecord" % (file_idx)
      start_idx = images_per_file * file_idx
      end_idx = start_idx + images_per_file
      example_counter += write_tfrecords(file_name, image_paths[start_idx:end_idx])
    return example_counter



 train_example_count = write_data(train_image_paths, num_train_files, train_files_prefix)
 print(f"{train_example_count} training examples were written to tfrecord files.")

 valid_example_count = write_data(valid_image_paths, num_valid_files, valid_files_prefix)
 print(f"{valid_example_count} evaluation examples were written to tfrecord files.")`
```

Error are in below two lines

`"caption": bytes_feature(caption.str.encode()),                                                                                       "raw_image": bytes_feature(tf.io.read_file(image_path).numpy()),`

Complete code is [in this Colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zE5tjf5xQgipBiPYNJVJl--SJhhCeTHf?usp=sharing).

Comment: How can string be encoded into bytes if you don't say what encoding to use? Just because getting past that bug gets you to a different bug doesn't mean you shouldn't fix the first one before you start trying to fix the second one.

Comment: As for the second error .. where is that file on disk? Have you considered generating an absolute path to it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in recent versions of Python, calling `encode` with no argument is fine; it defaults to 'utf-8'. @albert, What version of Python are you using? But yeah, there are two unrelated questions here; this should probably be split up.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments, My python version is `Python 3.7.13`. What should I do now, How to encode this string data?

Comment: I have looped through all images and saved it in image_path, when I print image_path prints `519_IM-2131-2001.dcm.png` which is an image name but at the end of loop when I print `image_paths` then the lenght images are `7470`.

Comment: HI, I have solved the `image_path` problem, Can anybody help me with encoding string problem.